# Codeigniter Controller and Routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to build a very simple web app using `codeigniter`, for now I am trying to build static pages for both the website and the admin area.

but any routing is giving

> 404 page

except the home controller.

I have 2 main folders containing the web pages, one is for the user

`application/views/pages/home.php`

and the other is for the admin.

`application/views/admin/dashboard.php`

I can access the home page, but I can't access the admin page.

here is the Pages controller:

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller {
  public function view($page = 'home')
  {
    $this->load->helper('html');
          if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
          {
             show_404();
          }

          $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter
          $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
          $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
          $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
  }
}
?>
```

and here is the admin controller

```
<?php
class Admin extends CI_Controller {
  public function view($admin = 'dashboard')
  {
          if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/admin/'.$admin.'.php'))
          {
                show_404();
          }
          $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);/* should be there*/
          $this->load->view('admin/'.$admin, $data);
  }
}
?>
```

and here is the routes

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/dashboard';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

I can access the home page, but I can't access the admin page. any help, please?

Comment: change $route['admin'] = 'admin/dashboard'; to $route['admin'] = 'admin/view';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Make sure you have loaded `url` helper and `.htaccess` and set `base_url` in config.php

Your **config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project_folder/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

In **autoload.php**

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

*`.htaccess` file should be like this :*

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

*place `.htaccess` file in your project_folder*

Replace

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/dashboard';
```

with this :

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/view';
```

*`route.php` should be like this :*

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/view';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Access url like this :

```
http://localhost/project_folder/
http://localhost/project_folder/admin
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

Comment: well, the same result, I did not create any .htaccess, but it's still giving Not Found

Comment: see my updated answer , just do like this and  see you u get the result

Comment: ok, now it's not giving 404, but it's giving `No input file specified.`

Comment: ok, working now, I had to add `?` sign to this rule 

before
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`

after
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 0):

i think code should like this..theres an error at your if part i've corrected it hope this is work for you.....

```
<?php
class Admin extends CI_Controller {
  public function view($admin = 'dashboard')
  {
          if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/admin/'.$admin.'.php'))
          {
                show_404();
          }else{
           $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);/* should be there*/
          $this->load->view('admin/'.$admin, $data);
          }

  }
}
?>
```